# How can I get the KeyStroke for an ENTER key using an ActionEvent?

Tags: java, swing, actionevent

I'm writing an application in Java where I need one thing to happen when the user presses letter keys and something different when the user hits ENTER but I can't seem to get a key name when I hit ENTER, only a new line.

I think I should be using getKeyStroke but I'm not sure if that's possible because I'm using ActionEvent.

This is what I'm doing so far:

```
panelMaster.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "doSomething");
panelMaster.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("B"), "doSomething");
panelMaster.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("C"), "doSomething");
panelMaster.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "ENTER" ), "doSomething");
panelMaster.getActionMap().put("doSomething", anAction);
```

Then I have a separate class with the Action.

```
class AnAction extends AbstractAction{        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + e.getActionCommand());
    }    
}
```

When I type two series of "a" then "b" then "c" then "ENTER" this is what my output looks like:

```
Received: a
Received: b
Received: c
Received: 

Received: a
Received: b
Received: c
Received:
```

Comment: If you want something different to happen when you use the Enter key, then create a custom Action. Don't try to share the same Action for all the KeyStrokes.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and although it does get the job done because it is a separate Action class I still can't use "e.getKeyStroke() or something similar that will tell me what key was pressed".   I don't know. I think I'm probably doing something really stupid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0)

Comment: I don't know why this confuses me so much.  I'm not sure where I I'm supposed to use the "(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0)" you suggest. I can use it instead of " ENTER "  when I'm declaring the event but still I can't do "e.getKeyStroke()" in the action.

Comment: Oh. I apologize for the confusion. I misinterpreted your question as not being able to detect the enter key being pressed.

Comment: The KeyStroke.getKeyStroke expects a certain type of string, as shown here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(java.lang.String)

When the string contains a single character, it expects a single unicode character. The unicode symbol for 'enter', or 'return', is shown here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23ce/index.htm

In Java, escape sequences are used to define unicode characters.

So in your case, "\u23CE" may be the string to recognize  the enter key. I don't know much about action events.

Comment: I don't think key names are used in Java so much as key strokes. The program isn't recognizing the key names; it's recognizing the unicode sequence generated by the key. You'll probably need an if statement to recognize the unicode sequence (in your ActionEvent), and print the word "Enter" manually.

Comment: I know I do a horrible job at explaining myself. I'm sorry.  
   If I could get "\u23CE" that would be great. The problem is that I don't receive anything. I just get a new line in the output window.  

I think this is happening because I'm using "e.getActionCommand()" instead of "e.getKeyStroke()".  

Unfortunately I can't use "e.getKeyStroke()" because netbeans gives me an error saying that I can't use a getKeyStroke() method on an ActionEvent variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
panelMaster.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
           .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "pressed ENTER" ), "doSomething");
panelMaster.getActionMap().put("doSomething", anAction);
```